# How to prove $(\sin x)^{\sin x}<(\cos x)^{\cos x}$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that $$(\sin x)^{\sin x}<(\cos x)^{\cos x}$$
if x is from $]0, \pi/4[$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Comment: Hey,i have no clue how to write mathematical expressions on the "ask question" category.

Comment: Learn mathJax in this case: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Simple :  $\sin x-\cos x=\sqrt2\sin(x-\pi/4)$

Comment: What sort of proof do you want; i.e.. What field of analysis?

Comment: One that uses arithmetic and geometric mean.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Transform the inequality to $\cos x \log \cos x - \sin x \log \sin x > 0$, and after some work, to $\log \cot x > (\cot x - 1)\log \sec x$. Then set $t = \cot x > 1$, and the inequality becomes $2 \log t > (t-1)\log (1 + 1/t^2)$. Now use the inequality $\log v \leq (v - 1)$ to prove $(t - 1)\log(1 + 1/t^2) \leq (t - 1)/t^2 \leq 1/4$. Finally prove $(t - 1)\log(1 + 1/t^2) \leq \min(1/4, (t - 1)\log 2)  < 2 \log t$ for $t > 1$.